# Android studio compilation error on debug

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to compile the app with android studio.

The error log for the process is here.
https://gist.github.com/barron9/ceab1339e422be50722db41c55c8c8fc

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    testBuildType = "validation"

    signingConfigs {
        release
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com..app."
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk { abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86' }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the points in applicationId:
applicationId "com..app." -> applicationId "com.app"

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell the exact reason ,but you can try below things:

- Try value with single quotes instead of double
- Try removing = from testBuildType